# What is the syntax for assigning the plugins property in Extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

What is the syntax for the plugin property in Ext.grid.Panel?  If I comment out the plugins property in the code below, it works fine, but it produces an error if left in.

```
this.grid = new Ext.grid.Panel( {
    id: "t-"+this.gridName+"-grid",
    header: true,
    title: gridTitle,
    selType : 'rowmodel',
    border: false,
    store: store,            
    columns: cm,
    selModel: sm,
    loadMask: true,
    provider: this.page.provider,
    viewConfig: {
        stripeRows: true
    },
    plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.ux.grid.GridHeaderFilters')]
});
```

Comment: This looks fine.  What error is it raising?  What does your column configuration and store look like?

Comment: Your code seems OK. `Ext.ux.grid.GridHeaderFilters` has quite a few bugs. See [this thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?150918-Grid-Header-Filters) for how to fix them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above syntax is perfectly right. Make sure that class you have created using Ext.create must have same name from define.

```
"Ext.define('Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander',{"
```

Also check init function. Whatever method you assign in grid.on i.e 'this.onRender', must exist in your plugin file. Sometimes for testing purpose we remove that and do not realise that.

```
init : function(grid){
        grid.on( 'render',        this.onRender,        this);

    },
```